VS Code Sync Changes: Always pushes to master
After commiting changes, when I click the "Sync changes"-Button it always tries to push to master, even though I am on another branch.
I am expecting it to push to the branch I am currently on.
Possible cause (in case this is not default behaviour): I am using a git sub-module inside my project.

First ensure that you are on the correct branch in the source control tab, open the command palette and type git checkout branch_name.
If the above fails then test the submodule to ensure it is aligned with the remote settings by typing git submodule update --remote.
In addition to the above i am pretty sure VSCode Git settings has some sort of stream defaults.
Also check .git/config

Unfortunately this didnt resolve the problem. Still thanks for your answer!

Another thing to try would be to check .git/config if configured properly.
In addition to the above, what happens if you manually push by git push origin your-current-branch ?

Cool! That's It! The problem was in the .git/config
It was configured wrongfully:
[branch "pangu-pytorch"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/main
vscode-merge-base = origin/main
To solve, I had to change merge to: merge = refs/heads/pangu-pytorch

awesome :) glad to be of help
